# How to call stored procedure in strongloop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using `MySQL` and `strongloop`, I have a stored procedure to swap data

```
swap_XYZ('<old_abc>', '<new_new>')
```

I am not able to find any example in the documentation to call stored procedure. How to call this stored procedure? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checking this [URL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html), hopefully it can help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
module.exports = function (ABCModel) {
 var ds = app.dataSources.dsMySQL;

  ABCModel.swap = function (old_abc, new_abc, cb) {

    var sql = "CALL `swap_XYZ`('" + old_abc + "','" + new_abc + "');";

    ds.connector.query(sql, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error:", err);
      }
      cb(null, data);
      console.log("data:", data);
    });
  }

  ABCModel.remoteMethod(
    'swap',
    {
      accepts: [
        {arg: 'old_abc', type: 'string'},
        {arg: 'new_abc', type: 'string'}
      ],
      returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'object'},
      http: {path: '/swap', verb: 'post'}
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer this link.
dataSource.connector.execute(sql, params, cb); or dataSource.connector.query(sql, params, cb);

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Database+connectors https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Executing+native+SQL

```
 module.exports = function(DemoModel) {
    var server = require('../../server/server');
      var ds = server.dataSources.MySQL;

    DemoModel.list = function(optionalparam, cb) {  


      var sql = 'select * from DemoModel';
      ds.connector.execute(sql, function(err, data)
      {
      if(err) return err;
      console.log(err);
      console.log("data",data);
        cb(null, data);
      });

    }

    DemoModel.remoteMethod(
        'list', 
        {
          accepts: {arg: 'param', type: 'string'},
          returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'object'},
          http: {path: '/list', verb: 'get'}
        }
    );


    };
```

Comment: I am trying this but getting error " Cannot read property 'connector' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I finally called stored procedure successfully..

First, we need to define `app` like Riaz as kather
`var app = require('../../server/server');`

But both `app.dataSources.MySQL` and `app.dataSources.dsMySQL` are not working for me. My loopback version is `loopback@3.17.1` and the correct property name for me is `app.dataSources.mysql;`

And then make sure your database user account has the privilege for calling stored procedure:

> **Granting Privileges on Functions/Procedures:** While using functions and
> procedures, the Grant statement can be used to grant users the ability
> to execute the functions and procedures in MySQL. **Granting Execute
> Privilege:** Execute privilege gives the ability to execute a function
> or procedure.
>
> **Syntax:**
>
> GRANT EXECUTE ON [ PROCEDURE | FUNCTION ] object TO user;

Quote from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-grant-revoke-privileges/

Answer (score 0):

Call PL/SQL stored procedure using node.js

Suppose the procedure's name is `getCountryName` and it takes one input parameter and one output parameter.

```
var executeProcedure = function () {
        var procedureName = "CALL GETCOUNTRYNAME(:inputVal,:outVal)";
        var oracledb = require('oracledb');
        oracledb.maxRows = 1;
        // oracledb.fetchAsString = [oracledb.CLOB];
        oracledb.getConnection(
            {
                user: 'user',
                password: 'password',
                connectString: "connectString"
            },
            function (err, connection) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);

                    return;
                }
                connection.execute(
                    procedureName,
                    {
                        outVal: {
                            type: oracledb.STRING,
                            dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT
                        },
                        inputVal: {
                            type: oracledb.STRING,
                            dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
                            val: 'IN'
                        }
                    },

                    function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);

                            return;
                        }
                       console(result)
                    });
            });
};
```

For more details

https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#queryinglobs
https://dzone.com/articles/plsql-record-types-and-the-nodejs-driver

https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/example.js